# Java spring: converter um file em MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, arquivo, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

Eu criei um arquivo simples:

```
File file = new File("text.txt");
```

Mas gostaria de converter este para um MultipartFile, qual seria a melhor forma?

Já tentei o código abaixo, sem sucesso:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", file.getName(), "text/plain", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

Obrigada.

Comment: Acho que [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936172/converting-file-to-multipartfile-with-spring/30588052) pode lhe ajudar

Comment: A primeira resposta já era o que eu tinha tentado, a segunda não funcionou também, apresentando o erro: (org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem) in CommonsMultipartFile cannot be applied to (org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma forma de fazer isso:

```
File file = new File("text.txt");
InputStream stream =  new FileInputStream(file)
MultipartFile multipartFileToSend = new MockMultipartFile("file", file.getName(), MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE, stream);
```